# trying to identify a lego set with no box or insturctions there is 9 numbered bags of parts and one sticker sheet with the number 77004 on it?

Tags: set-identification

there is 7 numbered bags of parts 3-9 and 4 unnumbered bags and one sticker sheet with the number 77004 on it ?
one bag has the number 1*77004.6.1.4
i have searched and can not find any set with that number
the sticker sheet looks like one that comes with the millennium falcon but not sure which version
any help please

Comment: Please add pictures. Quick search on LEGO fan pages didn't render any meaningful results, so it could be non-LEGO set.